# To keep some binaries in system memory

Tags: configuration

How do we have OS to keep some small executable binaries in system memory location never getting removed till manually instructed so, with purpose to prevent inefficiency repetitive read then load - close then unload the binary from storage and memory?

Comment: AFAIK the kernel won't *"unload the binary"* until it really needs to - see for example [How can I load an executable into the RAM for periodic calls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610742/65304) and [How does cached memory work for executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/how-does-cached-memory-work-for-executables)

Comment: Read `man chmod` especially the "Restricted Deletion Flag or Sticky Bit".. The "Sticky bit" was used, decades ago, back when memory was tiny. It's not needed now.